# how to write a spring test involving two data sources with two transaction managers

Tags: java, spring, testing, transactions

I am working on migration tool in which we fetch data from one database and insert\update data in another database.Once this update is successful we update  the status back in database 1.We have two data sources and two transaction managers. Now i want to write a spring integration test using AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringTestContexts class. Now the problem is it takes only one transaction manager . How can i write a test that can use both transaction manager and roll back the entire operations once the test are over.

Comment: I suppose you can just inject your both transaction manager in test code and manage transaction yourself.

Comment: Can u please guide me how to do that ,i searched forums and it turns out that the @Transactional annotation takes only one transaction manager.